# MySQL query with a Max row value with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table like this

| gen_loc | rev_number | status | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5A2 | 09 | PROCESSED | INSERT |
| 5A2 | 10 | PROCESSED | INSERT |
| 5A2 | 10 | PROCESSED | DELETE |
| 8A5 | 09 | PROCESSED | INSERT |
| 8A5 | 10 | PROCESSED | UPDATE |
| 10A6 | 09 | PROCESSED | INSERT |
| 10A6 | 10 | PROCESSED | DELETE |

I am trying to select the rows which contains the MAX value from rev_number column BUT ONLY IF THIS COLUMN ITS THE MAX VALUE WITH ACTION DIFFERENT TO DELETE AND EQUAL TO PROCESSED

As you can see, in the gen_loc 10A6 we have 10 as a max value but action delete so, I expect that the query doesn't show the gen_loc 10A6 for this case.
I have been trying other queries using MAX(rev_number) but it shows me still the gen_loc with 09 rev_number.

**I expect this result:**

| gen_loc | rev_number | status | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5A2 | 10 | PROCESSED | INSERT |
| 8A5 | 10 | PROCESSED | UPDATE |

**How to select a Max value with the condition that the action IS NOT DELETE AND STATUS EQUAL TO PROCESSED?**
Thank you!

Comment: You will require a PK in order to get the max records as per your conditions, Else 10A6 09 PROCESSED INSERT Will be considered as the max record , Also 10A6 09 PROCESSED INSERT Records wont be ignored

Comment: What've you tried so far? As you want to use MAX(), what column you want to use to group by?

Comment: PunitGajjar I am trying to get the max value which is not delete and processed. so thats, my question, how can I add the conditions? show the row if is the max value is not delete and processed? I case this 3 conditions doesnt match, dont show that row

Comment: learning - I have tried  queries similar in comments below. Yes the gen_loc column will be group with the max revision but I want to add other conditions to show the max value in case of match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9VHZMVtm8fZWZKPnQLanro/1)

If you don't want to group by any column, you can do in this way

```
SELECT tbl.* 
FROM tbl
JOIN
(
    SELECT max(rev_number) as t2_revNum
     FROM tbl
) t2 ON tbl.rev_number=t2.t2_revNum
WHERE status = 'PROCESSED' AND action <> 'Delete'
```

Comment: Hi learning. Thank you for your help, first off.
yes, the gen_loc will be grouped. I want to be able to show the row if and only if the MAX(rev_number) match with the conditions action !='DELETE' and status = 'PROCESSED'

In the queries I've tried if the max value match with action !='DELETE' and status = 'PROCESSED' it shows me one less number revision.

What I want is if the max revision doesnt match with the actions and status criteria, do jump to the less number revision, I mean dont show that row.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by it shows you one less number revision? Please include @ when you tag someone, thank you

Comment: I mean, lets say we have in the colum rev_number 10, 9 and 8 so
the max value is 10,
if the query doesn't match with the MAX(value) (this case 10), action != delete and status = 'PROCESSED' the query omit that MAX(value) and then go looking for the  next MAX(value) (next value = 09) until the query match with those conditions.
What I want is that if doesn't match with the first MAX(value) (for this example 10) DONT SHOW ME THE NEXT ONE (max value = 09)

I hope you can understande

Comment: @JorgeLedezma Meaning to say, should return 0 rows when MAX(value) is 10 but with action = delete and status = PROCESSED. Then this solution should be no issue. If you try to change action for all rev_number = 10, you will find that it returns no row

Comment: That's correct. I just find the solution! just missing to add t1.action <> 'DELETE' AND t1.status = 'PROCESSED at the end of the query and GROUP BY gen_loc, status to the query. I'll mark your answer as a the good one. Thank you so much for your heelp!